# Angular js: How to reload tab controller every time when get clicked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to reload my tab controller whenever the tab clicked. 
code is

```
$scope.tabs = [
  {
    id: 'tab1',
    title: 'tab1',
    icon: 'comments',
    templateUrl: 'tab1/tab1.tpl.html',
    load: true
  },
  {
    id: 'tab2',
    title: 'tab2',
    icon: 'user',
    templateUrl: 'tab2/tab2.tpl.html',
    load: false
  }
];

var activeTab = $scope.tabs[0].id;

$scope.selectTab = function(tab) {
  if (!tab.load) {
    tab.load = true;
  }
  activeTab = tab.id;
};

$scope.isActive = function(tab) {
  return tab === activeTab;
};
```

`$scope.selectTab()` is calling while clicks on tab. when I switch tabs I wanted to reload the controller of the tab.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Tab selection is not part of the core AngularJS framework. You need to specify which library you are using for tab selection. Also include the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't revealed your html template, so i'll try to guess what it looks like...

in controller:

```
$scope.activeTab = activeTab;
```

in html template:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <div class="tab-label" ng-click="selectTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</div>
    <div class="tab-content" ng-if="tab.id === activeTab">Tab content</div>
</div>
```

another way:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <div class="tab-label" ng-click="selectTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">{{tabs.find((tab) => tab.id === activeTab)}}</div>
```

There are more elegant ways, but they require to rework your whole code

P.S. ng-if totally reloads content of containng element when its expression toggles to true

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to reload the controller?

Maybe, you would like to have a look to [AngularJS Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), paragraph: **Creating Directives that Communicate**